# Need help understanding *args + reduce usage in Python

Tags: python

While trying to figure out a way to find the least common multiplier between n numbers, I came upon the following code:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    """Return greatest common divisor using Euclid's Algorithm."""
    while b:      
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    """Return lowest common multiple."""
    return a * b // gcd(a, b)

def lcmm(*args):
    """Return lcm of args."""   
    return reduce(lcm, args)
```

Everything makes sense until the last function: lcmm.

When I try:

```
>>> lcmm(range(1,5))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Whereas

```
>>> lcmm(*range(1,5))
12
```

which is the desired output.

To make things more confusing,

```
>>> reduce(lcm, range(1,5))
12
```

I've read a few articles on *args usage and reduce, but I'm having difficult time wrapping my head around combined usage in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `lcmm(*range(1,5))` you're unpacking the iterable `range(1, 5)` with `*` so you're actually calling `lcmm(1, 2, 3, 4)`. In other words, there are five arguments that don't have names but they're in order and they're passed in those positions. In the function `def lcmm(*args):` the `*` captures the positional arguments into `args`. This means `args` gets the value `(1, 2, 3, 4)`. That explains why you're getting the same as `reduce(lcm, range(1,5))` because that's the same as `reduce(lcm, args)` when `args = (1, 2, 3, 4)`.

When you're calling `lcmm(range(1,5))` it means you're passing `[1, 2, 3, 4]` as your argument. This is the only positional argument so at `def lcmm(*args):` the value of `*args` still captures all positional arguments. But because there's only one positional arguments the value of `args` becomes `([1, 2, 3, 4],)`. That's a tuple with one value in it, namely `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. This gives you a different result when `lcm` computes the return value.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that range(1,5) gets passed as a tuple. That was the missing piece I was looking for.

Comment: in the second paragraph, everywhere it says `range(1,5)` you actually mean the _result_ of `range(1,5)`, which is the list `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: @Anentropic: thanks, now updated. I was thinking about the `xrange` object but `range` indeed returns a list.

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` takes a function and a list of items to apply that function to, hence you use it like:
`reduce(lcm, range(1,5))`
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

The `*args` in `def lcmm(*args)` means the `lcmm` takes any number of *individual* arguments, and they will be made available as a tuple called `args` in the body of the function.

So you could call it like `lcmm(1, 2, 3, 4)` and `args` will be the tuple `(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

The `range` function returns a list, so to pass the result of `range(1,5)` into the `lcmm` function you need to use the `*` operator to 'unpack' the list into individual arguments:
`lcmm(*range(1,5))`

See docs:
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Answer (score 1):

The star takes a tuple (or other iterable) and turns it into arguments to a function:

```
foo(a, b, c)
```

is exactly the same as

```
bar = (a, b, c)
foo(*bar)
```

In the function definition,

```
def foo(*args):
    a, b, c = args
    # stuff
```

will do the same thing as

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    # stuff
```

Note that while those invocations are exactly the same, the definitions are slightly different because *args doesn't limit you to 3 arguments. So you'll get a different exception if you call those two functions with 4 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in python if you see `*x` in the parameter list it means it takes multiple parameters.  If you have a list to pass you need to unpack it on the call using `*mylist` as mentioned.

Similarly, if you see `**y` in the parameter list then you call it with zero or more keyword arguments.  So if you have dict object, my_dictionary, you use `**my_dictionary` to unpack it into keyword arguments to the function.

All functions and methods in python have the equivalent signature of `some_function(*args, **kwargs)` which can be very useful for decorators and other purposes.

Comment: _"All functions and methods in python have the equivalent signature of `some_function(*args, **kwargs)`"_ ...that's not true. Python functions and methods _can_ be defined that way but if they are not they will _not_ have that signature.